# Creating Pulsing Circles in an NVD3 scatterChart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

Because there's very little NVD3 documentation, I'm unsure about how to modify the code to create pulsing bubbles in a scatter chart. I'd like to be able to be able to iterate through an array of data for each bubble, and animate the size of the bubble based on that data, in a continuous loop. At the moment my code is pasting all the data points on top of each other as soon as the chart is called.

I've found various examples of doing something similar using D3, but nothing exactly the same. And I'm still not sure how I would apply this to NVD3 as it doesn't seem to use the same enter/exit way of doing things as D3. I've provided an example of my current code and data below. I've also created a JSFiddle so you can see it (not) working: http://jsfiddle.net/9oyaypz0/. Any help would be very greatly appreciated.

```
function makeScatter(data, div, showLabels,title) {
nv.addGraph(function() {
    var width = 450,
        height = 275;
    var chart = nv.models.scatterChart()
        .showDistX(true)
        .showDistY(true)
        .transitionDuration(350)
        .sizeRange([0, 10000])
        .margin({bottom:75})
        .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

    chart.tooltipContent(function(key, x, y, obj) {
      return '<h4>' + key + '</h4><h5 style="clear:both;line-height:0.1rem;text-align:center;">' + obj.point.size + '</h5>';
    });

    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) { return ''; });
    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function (d) { return ''; });
    chart.forceX([0]);
    chart.forceX([5]);
    chart.forceY([0]);
    chart.forceY([6]);
    chart.scatter.onlyCircles(false);

    if(title) {
        d3.select('title')
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", (width / 2))
            .attr("y", 100)
            .style("font-size", "16px")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(title);
        $(div).append("<h2>"+title+"</h2>");
    }

    d3.select(div)
        .datum(data)
        .transition().duration(1200)
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
});
};
```

And the data is like so:

```
var data = [{ key: "Test Bubble 1",
             values: [{ series: 0,
                        shape: "circle",
                        size: 1592,
                        x: 5,
                        y: 4 },
                      { series: 1,
                        shape: "circle",
                        size: 1560,
                        x: 5,
                        y: 4 },
                      { series: 2,
                        shape: "circle",
                        size: 1512,
                        x: 5,
                        y: 4 },
                      { series: 3,
                        shape: "circle",
                        size: 1487,
                        x: 5,
                        y: 4 }]
            },
            { key: "Test Bubble 2",
             values: [{ series: 0,
                        shape: "circle",
                        size: 592,
                        x: 5,
                        y: 4 },
                      { series: 1,
                        shape: "circle",
                        size: 560,
                        x: 5,
                        y: 4 },
                      { series: 2,
                        shape: "circle",
                        size: 512,
                        x: 5,
                        y: 4 },
                      { series: 3,
                        shape: "circle",
                        size: 487,
                        x: 5,
                        y: 4 }]
            }]
```